# jquery retrigger click after download

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, click, html5-audio

I'm trying to catch with JQuery when a user listens or downloads my songs and generate an event for Goole Analytics.

For interactions with the < audio > element it works fine but there are some troubles when the user downloads the song.

The code is:

```
$("audio").bind("play", function( event ){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Play', event.target.id );
});
$("audio").bind("ended", function( event ){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Ended', event.target.id );
});
$("a:contains('Download')").click(function( event ){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Download', event.target.id );
});
```

All Play and Ended events are catched, until the user for The first time clicks on the "Download" link. The first Download event is triggered correctly but from now on no more event is detected, neither Play or Ended.
I also tried:

```
$( document ).on("click" , "a:contains('Download')" , function( event ){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Download', event.target.id );
});
```

with similar results.

Comment: I can add that it seems related somehow to the appearance of the "save as" dialog box. I noticed that, in debug mode, if I replace `.click` with `.mouseover` the event is always detected but the "save as" dialog box does not appear.

Comment: Can you show us a code example? I'm not seeing this happen on a generic setup with similar html/js (demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CLwio), and without seeing it in front of me to debug, it's hard to guess what the issue is.

Comment: Here is the code.
HTML:
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/LAB.min.js"></script>`
`<script>
 $LAB
 .script("js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js").wait()
 .script("js/musicfunctions.js");
</script>`
`<head>``<audio id="Vita" controls preload="metadata">
<source src="/mp3/Mysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`
`<a href="/mp3/Mysong.mp3" download>Download</a>`
`</body>`
JS: the content of musicfunctions.js is the one on the main post.

Comment: Daniel, the code you showed is actually almost identical to mine, except for one small thing: the presence of `return false;` in the function under `$("a:contains('Download')")`. But that seems to make the difference. In fact with `return false;` the "save as" dialog box does not open and I see in my code too that everything works... but of course you cannot save the song in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.

The original problem was that I wanted to provide to visitors a button to download my songs, which opened a "save as" message box. My original code was to use the HTML *download* property:

```
<a href="/mp3/Mysong.mp3" downlaod >Download</a>
```

This solution had a couple of problems:

- Is not supported by all browsers
- When the message box appears, jQuery seems to stop listening to events in the page, so I cannot anymore (through Google Analytics) trace the number of times the user plays my songs.

My solution is the following one.

**HTML**: define a class (*TrackDownload*) associated to the download events

```
<a class="TrackDownload" href="/mp3/Mysong.mp3">Download</a>
```

**JS**: associate to the class *TrackDownload* the opening of a new frame, such a way jQuery goes on monitoring the main page while the song is downloaded in another page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a.TrackDownload").click(function( event ){
        ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Download', event.target.id );
    });
    $("a.TrackDownload").attr({target: '_blank',
        download: $(this).prop('href'),
        href : $(this).prop('href')
    });
    $("audio").bind("play", function( event ){
        ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'Play', event.target.id );
    });
});
```

**.htaccess**: at server level, define the fact that mp3 files don't have to played but downloaded. Such a way the new frame is not opened but converted in a "save as" message box.

```
<FilesMatch "\.mp3$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Maybe there are more elegant solutions but this one works.